# How does Wireshark sniff the packets?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

When I have Wireshark running on, say, 192.168.1.100, how is it able to capture the packets that 192.1.123 sends to the router or to another computer/device in the LAN?

My theory is that when a computer wants to send a packet it sends it to every computer on the network and if the ip (or is it the MAC?) match, it receives the packet, otherwise it drops it. That way, 192.168.1.100 receives the packet and Wireshark captures it.
If that's what happens, does it send only the ip, the MAC or both? If both, what's the need for both?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit to broad a question for this forum. You have to read up on routing, switches, hubs and that kind of stuff to understand the answer to your question.

That being said then what is basically going on is that wireshark puts your network card into a mode that tells it to read all packets sent to it, instead of dropping them like you seem to already know about. That does not mean that it is seeing all packets on the network. It is only seeing packets that are either sent to only 192.168.1.100 or are sent to all computers on the network. Unless of course you have a hub in your network, then your computer gets all the traffic that goes through that hub.

Computers that are connected to switches that are correctly set up (or not managed at all, most home switches are not managed) only get traffic that is meant for all computers or themselves, rest of the traffic they don't see. If you want to see all traffic on the net you need to either have a managed switch and copy all traffic to the port that your computer is hooked up or somehow monitor the traffic through the router (but then you only get traffic that is going outside of the network, not inside network traffic).

So if your 192.168.1.100 computer is seeing packets from 192.168.1.123 then either the latter is sending packets directly to your .100 computer or it is sending out requests to all the network. Computers are sending out requests to all computers on the network all the time, like ARP requests.

Comment: "wireshark puts your network card into a mode" - might be worth adding that it is called "promiscuous" mode. -  promiscuous mode turns off the comparison of destination MAC address to the NIC's own MAC address when receiving Ethernet frames. With this setting, the PC can see all Ethernet frames going past the NIC even if they aren't addressed to it.